# Simulation - Generate 10% outliers in y-values based on x-values condition(less than 2)

Tags: r

I am trying to generate 10% outliers in y-values based on x-values condition(less than 2). Below are the codes I tried but got the error message "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument".

```
o <- 4
N <- 40 
set.seed(1001)
for(i in 1:100){
  x1 <- runif(N,1,10)
  y1 <- 5 + x1
  change_idx <- sample((which(x1 <= 2)), o, replace = FALSE)
  y1[change_idx] <- rnorm(o, 20, 1)

}
```

Comment: @chinsoon No, I want to get the position of my x-values first so that i can change y-values become outliers

Comment: @chinsoon12 I have tried and there are x-values less than 2, I think the problem is with the sample(). I can do it without the loop successfully, but I dont know why it get error when I do the looping. As long as I loop for less than 40 times, it succeed.

Comment: try `print(length(which(x1 <= 2)))` before the sample. you will see that you are trying to take 4 samples from a vector of length less than 4

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks a lot, I got what you mean.